# Segmentation Fault on HashMap Implementation C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, segmentation-fault

The code for my implementation of a hashmap can be found below. I'm not exactly sure why it's seg. faulting. I believe it's something to do with the constructor or destructor, but can't seem to figure exactly what.

```
typedef struct _node
    {
        char *key;
        int value;          /* For this, value will be of type int */
        struct _node *next; /* pointer to the next node in the list */
    } node;


/* HashMap class */
class HashMap
{
private:
    node ** hashTable;
    int numSlots;
public:
    /* Initializes a hashmap given its set size */
    HashMap(int size)
    {
        numSlots = size;
        hashTable = new node*[size] ;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            hashTable[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    /* Deconstructor */
    ~HashMap()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++)
        {
            node *temp = hashTable[i];
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        delete [] hashTable;
    }

    /*** Hash function. ***/

    int hash(char *s)
    {
        int i;
        int sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; * (s + i) != '\0'; i++)
        {
            sum += *(s + i);
        }

        return (sum % numSlots);
    }

    /*
     *Free all the nodes of a linked list. Helper method for *deconstructor
     */
    void free_list(node *list)
    {
        node *temp;
        char *tempKey;
        int tempValue;
        while (list != NULL)
        {
            temp = list;
            tempKey = temp->key;
            tempValue = temp->value;
            list = list->next;
            if (tempKey != NULL)
            {
                delete(tempKey);
            }
            delete(temp);
        }
    }

    /* Create a single node. */
    node *create_node(char *key, int value)
    {
        node *result = new node();
        result->key = key;
        result->value = value;
        result->next = NULL;

        return result;
    }


    /*
     *Stores given key/value pair in hashmap
     *returns boolean for success/failure
     */

    void set (char* key, int value)
    {
        int keyValue = hash(key);
        node *current = hashTable[keyValue];
        node *original = current;
        node *newNode;
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            hashTable[keyValue] = create_node(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            while (current != NULL)
            {
                current = current -> next;
            }

            if (current == NULL)
            {
                newNode = create_node(key, value);
                newNode -> next = original;
                hashTable[keyValue] = original;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Return a float value representing the load factor 
     *(item in hash map)/(size of hash map) of the data structure.
    */

    float load()
    {
        float numUsed = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++)
        {
            if (hashTable[i] != NULL)
            {
                numUsed++;
            }
        }
        return (numUsed / numSlots);
    }

    /* Removes value corresponding to inputted key from table */

    int remove (char* key)
    {
        int keyValue = hash(key);
        node *listOfInterest = hashTable[keyValue];
        if (listOfInterest == NULL)
        {
            return -999;
        }
        int toReturn = listOfInterest -> value;
        delete(listOfInterest);
        return toReturn;
    }

    /*
     * Look for a key in the hash table.  Return -999 if not found.
     * If it is found return the associated value.
     */
    int get(char *key)
    {
        int keyValue = hash(key);

        node *listOfInterest = hashTable[keyValue];

        while (listOfInterest != NULL)
        {
            if (listOfInterest != NULL)
            {
                return listOfInterest->value;
            }
            listOfInterest = listOfInterest -> next;
        }

        return -999;
    }

    /* Prints hash table */

    void print_hash_table()
    {
        int i;
        node *listIterator = NULL;

        for (i = 0 ; i < numSlots ; i++)
        {
            listIterator = hashTable[i];
            while (listIterator != NULL)
            {
                printf("%s %d\n", listIterator->key, listIterator -> value);
                listIterator = listIterator -> next;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Please give us some idea as to where the error is; there is too much code to expect many people to look through it.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: How you debug a segmentation fault depends on your platform and, in some cases, your preferences. You haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: I believe it's the constructor. When I try to insert a key/value pair, it's seg.faulting.

Answer (score 0):

One likely crash is caused by create_node which stores an arbitrary pointer to a string via

```
result->key = key;
```

I'll be that you call it with some pointer to char that is destined to be soon inappropriately out of scope.  Perhaps struct node should use a std::string to make it more likely to work.  Or at least copy the string and create a destructor for node to dispose of that memory if you prefer C-style pointers.

Also, try Valgrind.  I'm pretty sure that the problem will be noted.